# openshift: git clone ssh:// freeze at remote: Compressing objects

Tags: git, ssh, openshift

I create an app and ran

```
git clone ssh://5***c@***.rhcloud.com/~/git/***.git
Cloning into '5***c'...
remote: Counting objects: 1400, done.
remote: Compressing objects:  19% (203/1065)
```

then it stuck there forever

cloning other repos from Github or Bitbucket works fine, one more thing

```
ssh 5***c@***.rhcloud.com
```

stuck forever till I hit ctrl+c few times then it lands me into remote shell, any idea what wrong?

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with openshift because I just connected using my phone wifi and success fully cloned repos, perhaps it has something to do with my home router.

Answer (score 0):

The TG799vn router has issues with SSH, there's no solution for this router  but you can also put:

```
Host *
   IPQoS 0x00
```

in `~/.ssh/config` and you are done.